# Is there any API, or method to get whatsapp Chat messages inside your app

Tags: android, ios, api, whatsapp

Is there any API provided by whatsapp, that lets other apps to extract chat messages from official whatsapp app, just like google/facebook does.

Is there any method which can export the chat messages of users. I read about some methods which requires decrypting database file created by whatsapp, is that the only way?

Comment: No official API, refer to this. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16284396/get-whatsapp-messages

Answer (score 5):

there is no way provided by Whatsapp. Only backups are encrypted, if you access to /data/data/com.whatsapp/databases/msgstore.db in your devices it is just a SQLite database that you may access directly via Android Java application or push it out the device and access to it via any other language on a computer.

You must root your device to get to the file, but there is no need to decrypt the database if you want to avoid that particular issue, taking the real database instead of a backup file.

Regards,