# How can I access whatsapp messages from an Android app?

Tags: android, message, whatsapp

I need to know if there is a smart way to access whatsapp messages, in order to read them and check for some text. I've already done this for Android messages. Could you help me? Thanks.

Comment: see this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8856874/get-all-messages-from-whatsapp

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is there any API, or method to get whatsapp Chat messages inside your app](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23535933/is-there-any-api-or-method-to-get-whatsapp-chat-messages-inside-your-app)